# python flask : TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

i have a problem in my code about python use framework flask. i dont know what error in my code. maybe my error in wtforms area. please help me

this my error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njyq2.png)

my file : setpassword.py

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint, request, redirect, url_for, abort, flash, current_app
from urlparse import urlparse, urljoin
from forms import SetpasswordForm
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user
from models import Partner, User, mail, db
from flask_mail import Message
import uuid

setpassword_blueprint = Blueprint('setpassword', __name__)


@setpassword_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def setpassword():
    form = SetpasswordForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print "halo"
    return render_template('forms/setpassword.html', form=form)
```

setpassword_form.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo


class SetpasswordForm(FlaskForm):
     password = StringField('Password', [Length(min=6, max=20, message='Password minimal 6 karakter dan maksimal 20 karakter.')], [DataRequired()])
     confirm_password = StringField('Confirm Password', [EqualTo('password', message='Password dan Confirm password tidak sama.')], [DataRequired()])

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    FlaskForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Your `__init__` is not aligned within `SetpasswordForm` class. Is it aligned the same in your codebase or a typo?

Comment: oh yes, its typo

Comment: Please don't post the error as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc - https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#field-definitions, while initializing the form elements, the validators should be passed in a single list and not multiple lists separated by commas.

```py
password = StringField('Password', 
                     [Length(min=6, max=20, message='Password minimal 6 karakter dan maksimal 20 karakter.'),
                     DataRequired()]
)
```

Comment: wow amazing, cause you i solved this case. thank you!